# QGIS 3.4 Select by Location Returns Geometry Error - Processing Settings Ignored

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, geoprocessing, ubuntu

I am using QGIS 3.4 on Ubuntu 18.04.  I have a county wide city boundary polygon layer and a county wide building footprint polygon layer.  I would like to select all the buildings that are within a selected city polygon.  Both datasets share the same CRS.
When I use *Vector - Research Tools - Select by Location* the tool returns no selected features but it does return the error below.  On investigation I see that you can set the *Processing Options - General - Invalid features filtering* setting to *ignore features with invalid geometries*.  This setting has no effect on the tool which again, returns no selection.  I have used the *Fix Geometries* tool in the Processing Toolbox but still no selection is returned.  Why can I not perform a select by location on these data?

```
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Select by location' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'INPUT' : 'MultiPolygon? crs=EPSG:2285&field=YEAR:double(18,11)&field=TYPE:string(25,0)&field=NAME:string(50,0)&field=NUM_FLOORS:double(18,11)&field=APPRAISAL:double(18,11)&field=BLDGTYPE:string(20,0)&field=YRBUILT:double(18,11)&field=STYLE:string(20,0)&field=SF_1ST:double(18,11)&field=SF_2ND:double(18,11)&field=SF_3RD:double(18,11)&field=SF_ATTIC:double(18,11)&field=SF_LOFT:double(18,11)&field=TOTAL_SF:double(18,11)&field=SF_BASEMEN:double(18,11)&field=OWNER:string(50,0)&field=GLOBALID:string(38,0)&field=RuleID:long(10,0)&field=created_us:string(254,0)&field=created_da:date(10,0)&field=last_edite:string(254,0)&field=last_edi_1:date(10,0)&field=SHAPE_Leng:double(18,11)&field=SHAPE_Area:double(18,11)&uid={d01536ed-3181-4ec9-9044-7f52e58136b0}', 'INTERSECT' : QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition('WhatcomCityLimits_beaad58e_2210_456a_b1ba_0e407406cef5', True), 'METHOD' : 0, 'PREDICATE' : [0] }

Feature (7) has invalid geometry and has been skipped. Please fix the geometry or change the Processing setting to the "Ignore invalid input features" option.
Execution completed in 0.08 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': <qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x7fa7a888b5e8>}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Select by location' finished
```

**Edited:**  Setting the processing option to Do Not Filter allowed the Select by Location to process although I do not understand why Ingnore invalid inputs did not.